Failed to fetch current robot state when using MGI in wall timer callback function
I'm trying to use move_group_interface to get robot pose at a certain rate. So I put move_group_interface->getCurrentPose() in a function, and use create_wall_timer to create a timer and call my function. But when I do so, It says "Failed to fetch current robot state" and pose in every axis is 0.  Then I tried put move_group_interface->getCurrentPose() in a loop, and bind them to a new thread, this time it can work properly.
I really wonder why I can't use wall timer to call move_group_interface->getCurrentPose(). I'm not sure whether I make any mistake while using wall timer or there is some feature I don't know. Any clue would be appreciate.
Environment:

ROS2 Humble
MoveIt2

This example can reproduce different result when using two method. Output is also listed below.
#include <rclcpp/rclcpp.hpp>
#include <moveit/move_group_interface/move_group_interface.h>

#include <string>
#include <thread>


using namespace std;
using moveit::planning_interface::MoveGroupInterface;


class MotionPlan : public rclcpp::Node
{
  string planning_group;
  std::shared_ptr<moveit::planning_interface::MoveGroupInterface> move_group_interface;

  geometry_msgs::msg::PoseStamped current_pose;
  rclcpp::TimerBase::SharedPtr motion_plan_timer;
  std::thread* spinner;

public:
    MotionPlan();
    void motionPlan();
    void motionPlanThread();
    void launch_node();
};

MotionPlan::MotionPlan() : Node("motion_plan", 
rclcpp::NodeOptions().automatically_declare_parameters_from_overrides(true))
{
  planning_group = "ur_manipulator";
}

void MotionPlan::launch_node()
{

  rclcpp::executors::MultiThreadedExecutor executor;
  executor.add_node(shared_from_this());
  spinner = new std::thread([&executor]() { executor.spin();});


  move_group_interface = std::make_shared<moveit::planning_interface::MoveGroupInterface>(shared_from_this(),
                          planning_group );


  //leave one of the following two blocks uncomment to test
  //using create_wall_timer to call MotionPlan::motionPlan, won't work
  motion_plan_timer = this -> create_wall_timer(100ms, std::bind(&MotionPlan::motionPlan, this));

  //using std_thread to bind MotionPlan::motionPlanThread work properly
  std::thread t = std::thread(&MotionPlan::motionPlanThread, this);
  t.join();


  spinner -> join();
}


void MotionPlan::motionPlan()
{
  current_pose = move_group_interface -> getCurrentPose();

  std::cout << current_pose.header.stamp.sec << endl;
      std::cout << current_pose.pose.position.x << " " 
      << current_pose.pose.position.y << " "
      << current_pose.pose.position.z << " " << endl;
  return;
}

void MotionPlan::motionPlanThread()
{
  while(true)
  {
    current_pose = move_group_interface -> getCurrentPose();
    std::cout << current_pose.header.stamp.sec << endl;
    std::cout << current_pose.pose.position.x << " " 
      << current_pose.pose.position.y << " "
      << current_pose.pose.position.z << " " << endl;
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(100ms);

  }
}


int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  rclcpp::init(argc, argv);
  auto motion_plan = std::make_shared<MotionPlan>();
  motion_plan -> launch_node();

  return 0;
}

When using create_wall_timer to call MotionPlan::motionPlan, I got error below:
[robot_control-3] [INFO] [1716554369.338071196] [moveit_ros.current_state_monitor]: Didn't received robot state (joint angles) with recent timestamp within 1.000000 seconds.   
[robot_control-3] Check clock synchronization if your are running ROS across multiple machines!   
[robot_control-3] [ERROR] [1716554369.338103696] [move_group_interface]: Failed to fetch current robot state   
[robot_control-3] 1716554369   
[robot_control-3] 0 0 0   

When using std_thread to bind MotionPlan::motionPlanThread, I got correct output:
[robot_control-3] 1716554657   
[robot_control-3] 0.120113 0.431763 0.146073    
[robot_control-3] 1716554657  
[robot_control-3] 0.120113 0.431763 0.146073   


Thank you for your post. I was unable to get the poses at all for my robot, but your sample (the working part) works for me too.
